# derivative with numpy.diff problems

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have this problem:

I have an array of 7 elements:

```
vector = [array([ 76.27789424]), array([ 76.06870298]), array([ 75.85016864]), array([ 75.71155968]), array([ 75.16982466]), array([ 73.08832948]), array([ 68.59935515])]
```

(this array is the result of a lot of operation)

now I want calculate the derivative with numpy.diff(vector) but I know that the type must be a numpy array.

for this, I type:

```
vector=numpy.array(vector);
```

if I print the vector, now, the result is:

```
[[ 76.27789424]
 [ 76.06870298]
 [ 75.85016864]
 [ 75.71155968]
 [ 75.16982466]
 [ 73.08832948]
 [ 68.59935515]]
```

but If i try to calculate the derivative, the result is `[]`.

Can You help me, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could You show, how are You trying to calculate derivative, please?

Comment: der=numpy.diff(vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector` is a list of arrays, to get a 1-D NumPy array use a list comprehension and pass it to `numpy.array`:

```
>>> vector = numpy.array([x[0] for x in vector])
>>> numpy.diff(vector)
array([-0.20919126, -0.21853434, -0.13860896, -0.54173502, -2.08149518,
       -4.48897433])
```

Answer (score 1):

> vector = numpy.array(vector);

gives you a two dimensional array with seven rows and one column

```
>>> vector.shape
(7, 1)
```

The shape reads like: `(length axis 0, length axis 1, length axis 2, ...)`

As you can see the last axis is `axis 1` and it's **length is `1`**.

from the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)

> numpy.diff(a, n=1, **axis=-1**)
>   ...
>   axis : int, optional
>   The axis along which the difference is taken, **default is the last axis**.

There is no way to take difference of a single value. So lets try to use the first axis which has a length of `7`. Since axis counting starts with zero, the first axis is `0`

```
>>> np.diff(vector, axis=0)
array([[-0.20919126],
       [-0.21853434],
       [-0.13860896],
       [-0.54173502],
       [-2.08149518],
       [-4.48897433]])
```

Note that every degree of derivative will be one element shorter so the new shape is `(7-1, 1)` which is `(6, 1)`. Lets verify that

```
>>> np.diff(vector, axis=0).shape
(6, 1)
```